# Can we add Cell border for every row data in Excel writer or Excel output in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am working on Pentaho data integration and I am appending data into an excel sheet. Data is appending into the excel sheet perfectly but I need to provide the border for every cell. Is there anyway anybody can suggest me?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of Template feature of Microsoft Excel Output and Writer Steps.

**1.** Create a template with a cell having a border as per your requirement:

[image]

**2.** Use Microsoft Excel Writer step to define the template:

[image]

Make sure to make use of "write to existing sheet" in Excel.

**3.** In the field section of the Step, make sure to add the style Cell number. In my case it was D2 cell. This will read the data and add border to your data set.
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Final Output:

[image]